# Sharing a UINavigationItem among different ViewControllers

Tags: ios

I have a requirement to implement an app that has a navigation bar like bar at the top of numerous screens.

It has an icon on the left, some text, and some buttons on the right thus these would map well to a navigation item's left bar button items, title view, and right bar button icons.

However on most of the screens the content of the bar remains the same - i.e. a back button and title change would only appear occasionally for some screens, and on others the navigation bar would be present but is not actually used for navigational purposes.

Is the best of implementing this to configure a UINavigationItem, if so as there are multiple screens and multiple view controllers is there anyway the same UINavigationItem can be shared? That way I can configure the UINavigationItem in the RVC and keep it there as different view controllers get pushed, replacing it where need be when a back button does actually need to appear?

If this isn't the best approach then what alternatives are there? I experimented with making my RVC a container view controller and adding the bar as a view of that, that works for the immediate child view controllers but not for grandchild view controllers (which would take up the entire screen and not the portion alloted to them by the container view).

Comment: Is there any problem, or is this just speculation?

Comment: The title says "sharing a UINavigationItem", and the text additionally asks "is there anyway the same UINavigationItem can be shared?". Because when the views/VCs are created in a Storyboard IB automatically generates a separate UINavigationItem for each VC - therefore to customize each one multiple times would be a headache

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The navigationItem in UIViewController is readonly, so you can't have a single shared UINavigationItem shared between view controllers.  You could have a base view controller class that manages setting the navigation item that you derive all of your view controllers from.  To keep your classes from getting too coupled you could have it update the contents of the navigationItem from a NSNotification.  Then you can just post a notification when you need all of the navigation items to be updated.

Comment: Thanks. Each time a VC gets pushed/popped there would still be a different navigation item getting push/popped each time correct? However is there any chance there would be visible flicker as a new one gets pushed even if identical in appearance to the previous one?